# Расшифровка названий C++

Tags: c++

Есть ли сайт где указаны все расшифровки названий для C++ (например как расшифровывается cout = console output; endl = end line; iostream = input output stream и т. д.)

Comment: cout - characters output

Comment: Если кому то делать нечего и готов  заниматься этим бесполезным  делом, то может и есть...

Comment: ну мало ли. Ведь эти названия не просто так появились, а зная расшифровку легче язык учить

Comment: Это звучит как: "зная расшифровку  марок станков, легче изучать технологию производства ". Нет, все наоборот...

Comment: Вы же как-то узнали эти расшифровки? О смысле большинства сокращений можно догадаться.

Comment: В стандартах Си и Си++ всё расписано. `C++` : "The object `cout` **controls output** to a stream buffer associated with the object **stdout**" .. `C` : "the output stream `stdout` is referred to as **standard output**"

Answer (score 1):

Заходите на сайт

[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com)

и в строке поиска вводите `std::endl`, далее перейдя
по ссылке

[std::endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) - попадаете на статью с описанием, что это такое, но не названия